# Python soundfile audio client to Matlab server over sockets

Tags: python, matlab, audio

I have a requirement to read an audio WAVE file from Python and transfer the data to a remote server socket listening on a particular port in MATLAB. I am trying to use the soundfile module in Python for this. I find that the audio data is not getting transferred as is to the MATLAB server and because of which the transferred audio data is not playing in the server.

Here is my code on the client (Python):

```
   import soundfile as sf
   s = socket.socket()
   port = 30000
   s.connect(('127.0.0.1',port))

   data, samplerate = sf.read('speechrecord.wav')
   s.send(data)
   s.close()
```

Here is the code on MATLAB server side:

```
   t=tcpip('127.0.0.1', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
   fopen(t);
   data = char(fread(t,128,'float'))
   fclose(t);
```

Tried different combinations of reading the audio data on MATLAB side with different usages of fread. But none of the combinations seems to work.

The connection was successful. The Python client code successfully got connected to the MATLAB server ("fopen" call in server came out of blocking state). There was data that was also getting generated on the client and then sent to the server. However the data that was received on the MATLAB server using this fread call was completely different (not even one byte matched) with what has been sent by the client.

If any one has got this combination working for transferring audio data, then kindly let know the best way of achieving this objective.

Comment: Your question is lacking essential information. Are you able to connect? Transfer something? Have you looked at the data? What's the difference?

Comment: @JamesZ The connection was successful. The Python client code successfully got connected to the MATLAB server ("fopen" call in server came out of blocking state).
There was data that was also getting generated on the client and then sent to the server. However the data that was received on the MATLAB server using this fread call was completely different (not even one byte matched) with what has been sent by the client.

Comment: You should update your question with this information.

Comment: On the Matlab side you are reading the input as a vector of floats. Try to read it out as a byte vector, store it to a temporary file and then use `audioread` to parse the WAV format.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Your problems are manifold sadly. They stem mainly from the following lines and perhaps a couple of misconceptions.

**MATLAB**

```
data = char(fread(t, 128, 'float'))
```

**Python**

```
s.send(data)
```

In Python you are sending floats over the socket and then casting them as a character array. This will just round everything to `0` you end up with an array of ASCII `0` / NULL characters. [Check the char docs for more info](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html)

I don't believe the endianness when data is sent from python is correct either. So, you'd want to look into using the [struct package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to [format your data correctly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).

### Solution

I would say it is more important to setup the MATLAB server to be listening before trying to connect on the specified socket / port in python to avoid a `ConnectionRefusedError`

You need to pack the floats into a `bytearray`, which is why the `struct` package is imported. For a single sample, this is achieved by this function call:

```py
bytearray(struct.pack(">f", sample))
```

NOTE: The instrument toolbox `tcpip()` object appears to be big-endian by default.

The below scripts just sends the first `100` samples of the audio file. The next task is to create a system where you check for successful transfer. In the socket docs words:

*Applications are responsible for checking that all data has been sent; if only some of the data was transmitted, the application needs to attempt delivery of the remaining data. For further information on this topic, consult the [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#socket-howto).*

For playback, [`soundsc()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/soundsc.html) should do the job as it will normalise audio before playback and avoid any nasty noises.

**MATLAB**

Bear in mind this will still only read `100` values.

```matlab
t = tcpip('localhost', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
fopen(t);                       % this is blocking block until a connection is made
data = fread(t, 100, 'float');  % this is blocking until it receives 100 floats
fclose(t);
plot(data);
disp(data); % sanity check, should be the same as Python script print
```

**Python**

and this will only send the first `100` values.

```py
import soundfile as sf
import socket
import struct

audio_file_path = 'path/to/audio.wav'
data, sample_rate = sf.read(audio_file_path)
data_bytes = bytearray()

s = socket.socket()
port = 30000
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))

for sample in data[0:100]:
    data_bytes = data_bytes + bytearray(struct.pack(">f", sample))

s.send(data_bytes) # blocks until all data sent
s.close()

print(data[0:100]) # sanity check
```

### Dependencies

Dependencies for the above code are:

#### MATLAB

- [Instrument Control Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/index.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav)

#### Python

- [SoundFile](https://github.com/bastibe/SoundFile)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed troubleshooting information from your side. Really appreciate it.
When running the modified code, the python3 is letting out the following error:

struct.error: required argument is not a float 

on the line where we are using the bytearray() method:
data_bytes = data_bytes + bytearray(struct.pack("@f", sample))

Are we missing anything very simple here for the program to work>

Comment: #fdcpp Tried it with
data_bytes = data_bytes + bytearray(struct.pack(">f", sample))
and got the same error.

Comment: It seems to be working fine for myself running `Python 3.7.1`. Try simply running `type(sample)` and printing the value to determine what it is in your case.